# passing string 2d array to a function

Tags: c++

I am passing string 2d array to a function in a following way. Is it correct or can it be done better ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void print_name(string name[])
{
    cout<<name[0];
}

int main()
{
    string name[4];
    name[0] = "abc";
    name[1] ="xyz";
    name[2] = "pqr";
    name[3]= "xyq";

    print_name(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is better to think of it as an array of strings and not a 2d array even if a string is an array basically.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Maybe better to use `vector<string> name(4)` here.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ a better way is to pass a `std::vector` as the parameter.

```
void print_name(const std::vector<std::string>& name)
```

and

```
std::vector<std::string> name{"abc", "xyz","pqr","xyq"};

print_name(name);
```

Comment: `const` is needed here? You cannot change it even without `const`, right?

Comment: @herohuyongtao missed the reference.

Comment: Why not simply `void print_name(vector<std::string> name)`?

Comment: Passing the array is actually simpler (in this case) array[0] is always valid!

Comment: because for printing you dont need to change it? ;)

Comment: @DieterLücking only if you actually pass an array of size at least 1.

Comment: isn't `std::array` a better solution?

Comment: @tenfour if you know the size beforehand, maybe.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore int a[0]: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ‘a’

Comment: @DieterLücking sure, but the function, as is declared in the question, can take a pointer as parameter as well. `string* X = NULL; print_name(x);` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @DieterLücking in a parameter declaration, `void print_name(string name[])` and `void print_name(string* name)` are **exactly the same**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with passing C-style arrays is that the function that you call does not know where it ends. If you must use a fixed-size array, a better approach would be to pass `std::array<std::string,4>`:

```
void print_name(std::array<std::string,4>& names) ...
```

If using `std::vector<std::string>` is acceptable, it would give your code more flexibility:

```
void print_name(std::vector<std::string>& names) ...
```

If none of the above works for you, consider passing the number of array items along with the array, so that your `print_name` knows how may items it gets:

```
void print_name(std::string names[], int count) ...
```

Comment: hmm I think, you are correct I should use vector string... Thx a lot for your response.